# Rails 4 field type for multiselect with predefined values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, enums, multi-select

Heres the situation:
I have a Category model, which needs to have an attribute where the user can select multiple items from 3-4 predefined values (meaning only I can add more, the admins can't, so there is no separate model for those 3-4 options).

Enum would be great but with that, only 1 option can be selected.
Since I am using Postgres, I am thinking about using an array type attribute to store the selected values.

Is there a simpler, more efficient way to do this or another field type which I am just not aware of?

UPDATE (What I chose to do):

**Migration (Postgres 9.3):**
add_column :categories, :settings, :string, array: true, default: '{}'

**Controller:**
Added `:settings => []` to permitted params.

**View:** `<%= f.select :settings, %w[a b c], {}, :multiple => true %>`

So if I would like to get all categories where setting 'a' is present then I an do:

```
Category.where("'a' = ANY (settings)")
```

Comment: you want to [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) field?

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking about using an array type attribute to store the selected values.

You can [`serialize your field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) to save values as  array or hash in database. For this first you'll have to add a field in categories table by creating a migration

```
class some_migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :some_field, :text
  end
end
```

In model tell rails to use it as a serializable field

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :some_field, Array
end

#this will allow you to do something like this:
category = Category.create(some_field: [some_value_1,some_value_2])
Category.find(category.id).preferences # => [some_value_1, some_value_2]
```

Comment: Hi Mandeep, Thank You for Your quick and detailed reply. I updated my answer with my current solution. But I will try out Yours too!

Comment: :serialize was ye old standard answer to this in Rails, but I think Mate's use of array structures in Postgres is preferable. With serialize, the data only becomes meaningful at the app level, once ActiveRecord deserializes it for you. With postgres arrays, you can operate on the data at the db level if needed. See e.g. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98550/70848 and http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/07/rails-4-and-postgresql-arrays/ .

Comment: @Jacob but what if in future you would want to change your database then it'll give you headaches and I think you can even combine both approaches too, although I haven't tested it but I think it'll work